# insert data into stringlist after doing comparison

Tags: delphi

hi i have stringlist...in my stringlist if item_type<> 'remark' and gL_dept<>'' will checking the record..
if the record in gl_dept have same value for example 400,400,401..the value for 400 comes out 2 times
so only add 400 for one time only then it will go to next record..but my problem is
when i do comparison if lstDept.indexOf(sdept)<> -1 not going to this statement but it will back to this statement.. if (tblSODitemtype)..
how can i add the value into my stringlist..

```
  lstDept := TStringList.Create;  
  tblSOD.DisableControls;  
  try       
    tblSOD.First;  
    while (not tblSOD.Eof) do begin  
      sDept := tblSODGL_DEPT.AsString;  
      if (tblSODITEM_TYPE.AsString <> 'REMARK') and  (tblSODGL_DEPT.AsString <> '' ) then begin  
         if lstDept.IndexOf(sDept) <> -1  then begin  
            lstDept.add(tblSODGL_DEPT.asstring);  
            tblSOD.Next;  
         end;    
      end;  
    end;  
  finally  
    tblSOD.EnableControls;  
    lstDept.Free;  
  end;
```

Answer (score 9):

i think the problem is the position of the `tblSOD.Next` function call

try changing this

```
while (not tblSOD.Eof) do begin  
  sDept := tblSODGL_DEPT.AsString;  
  if (tblSODITEM_TYPE.AsString <> 'REMARK') and  (tblSODGL_DEPT.AsString <> '' ) then begin  
     if lstDept.IndexOf(sDept) <> -1  then begin  
        lstDept.add(tblSODGL_DEPT.asstring);  
        tblSOD.Next;  //Problem 
     end;    
  end;  
end;
```

to this

```
while (not tblSOD.Eof) do begin  
  sDept := tblSODGL_DEPT.AsString;  
  if (tblSODITEM_TYPE.AsString <> 'REMARK') and  (sDept <> '' ) then begin
     if lstDept.IndexOf(sDept) <> -1  then 
        lstDept.add(sDept);                
  end;
  tblSOD.Next;  
end;
```

Comment: Furthermore, there are a couple of extra calls to tblSODGL_DEPT.AsString which could be replaced with sDept.